# Simplify repetitive jQuery function

Tags: jquery

This code feels very repetitive, and I am sure there is a more efficient way to write it. Any help would be much appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

      $('.perry_1_txt').keyup(function(){
         $('.perry_1').text($(this).val());
      });

      $('.perry_2_txt').keyup(function(){
         $('.perry_2').text($(this).val());
      });

      $('.perry_3_txt').keyup(function(){
         $('.perry_3').text($(this).val());
      });

      $('.perry_4_txt').keyup(function(){
         $('.perry_4').text($(this).val());
      });

      $('.perry_5_txt').keyup(function(){
         $('.perry_5').text($(this).val());
      });

      $('.perry_6_txt').keyup(function(){
         $('.perry_6').text($(this).val());
      });     

});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<input class="perry_1_txt" /><span class="perry_1"></span>
<input class="perry_2_txt" /><span class="perry_2"></span>
<input class="perry_3_txt" /><span class="perry_3"></span>
<input class="perry_4_txt" /><span class="perry_4"></span>
<input class="perry_5_txt" /><span class="perry_5"></span>
<input class="perry_6_txt" /><span class="perry_6"></span>
<input class="perry_7_txt" /><span class="perry_7"></span>
</div>
```

The code dynamically takes the value from the inputs and places them in the corresponding span. It works fine, but it less than elegant.

Comment: What is repetitive, and what isn't? Shouldn't be hard once you [find a selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that helps you find the element's you want.

Comment: Could you give some HTML to demonstrate the structure here?

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for http://s.tk/review.

Comment: Efficient jQuery is only possible with efficent markup. I would recommend reconsidering your markup. Can you add a generic class to all these elements and use that as a selector? You could also reference the element your changing using a data attribute.

Comment: @colin thanks for showing some markup. I've edited my answer based on that - you really don't need any class names. You can take advantage of your HTML structure to simplify the HTML _and_ the JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use fewer class names, and store the index somewhere else.

#### HTML

```
<input class="perry_txt" data-index="1"/>
<input class="perry_txt" data-index="2"/>
<input class="perry_txt" data-index="3"/>
<!-- etc. -->
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    $('.perry_txt').keyup(function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this),
            i = $this.data('index');

        $('.perry_' + i).text($this.val());
    });
});
```

---

### Edit

Okay, so you've shown some HTML. We can do even better, and **don't *need* a single class name**:

#### HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <input /><span></span>
    <input /><span></span>
    <input /><span></span>
    <input /><span></span>
    <input /><span></span>
    <input /><span></span>
    <input /><span></span>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#parent').on('keyup', 'input', function ()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().text($this.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I never really understood using multiple class names to point to a single element (instead of, say, an ID or some other identifier).

Comment: Looks like i'm abit late. If you need an another example http://jsfiddle.net/E2MPD/

Answer (score 2):

What you are feeding to the jQuery functions are css selectors. And these inside the JS are mere strings. Which mean you can generate them on the fly.

```
$(function(){

   for(var e=1;e<7;e++){
      (function(){
        var i=e;
        $('.perry_'+i+'_txt').keyup(function(){
           $('.perry_'+i).text($(this).val());
        });
      })();
   }

}
```

Comment: Did you try this?  It won't work because the value of `i` will be 7 for all values of the callback function.

Comment: It's probably not the best solution - but no better one can be provided w/o knowing the HTML structure.

Comment: @jfriend00 your right, I added a closure around it. it will work now.

Comment: How do you know `7` is the extent of the elements to add a handler to on the page?

Comment: @JaredFarrish [1;6] it's what he asked to get simplified.